# Show that $ \sum n|A_n| $ converges

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $ A_n =\lbrace  x \in \Omega : n+1 \geq |f(x)| > n \rbrace$ for $f$ an integrable function over an open set $\Omega$ included in $ \mathbb{R}^d $.

How can you show that $ \sum n|A_n| $ converges ?

You can use the fact that for all $\epsilon > 0 $, there exist a set $E$ of measure $ \leq \epsilon$ and such that $f$ is bounded over the complementary of $E$. You prove that with Markov's inequality.

Comment: What is $|A_n|$? Do you mean $\mu(A_n)$, the measure of the set?

Comment: Yes, I meant that.

Comment: The answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/618646/418148) should help.

Comment: Yes, it did @B.Mehta

Comment: You are using $n$ for too many things.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you stated the question correctly. If we consider $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ over $(0,1)$. Then $A_n=(0,\frac{1}{n^2})$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n |A_n|$ is infinity.

Comment: You are right. I corrected the mistake.

Comment: you can consider $\cup_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n\subset \Omega$, and consider the $L^1$ norm on these two measurable sets.